How do I make iOS Homescreen widgets have consistent padding
I'm trying to design a homescreen widget but I am unable to properly control the padding and sizing of various components. In the four attached screenshots you can see the huge variation in padding around the outside, the change in text colour and the spacing between the text. I've boiled it down as simple as possible and put the view code below.
What I'd like to achieve is a consistent look between iPads and iPhones and ideally in the simulator too. Is there a simple way to set the padding so that all places use the same, and then scale the text so that I know that if the text fits in the simulator the same text will fit on all devices?




var body: some View {
    let dailyRows = entry.rows
    let commonFontSize = 20.0
    
    
    return Link(destination: URL(string: "widget://code?id=\(entry.code.id)")!) {
        ZStack {
            GeometryReader { geo in
                VStack {
                    Text("header")//entry.combinedForecast.location.name)
                        .frame(height: geo.size.height * 0.2)
                        .padding(2)
                        .font(.system(size: 24))
                        .lineLimit(1)
                        .minimumScaleFactor(0.05)
                        .frame(height: geo.size.height * 0.15, alignment: .center)
                        .border(.green)
                    
                    
                    ForEach(dailyRows, id: \.start) { summary in
                        VStack(spacing: 0) {
                            HStack {
                                Text("left")
                                Spacer()
                                Text("middle")
                                Spacer()
                                Text("right")
                            }
                        }
                        .padding(0)
                        .border(.purple)
                        if summary != dailyRows.last {
                            Rectangle()
                                .frame(height: 1)
                                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                              }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .border(.red)
    .padding(0)
    .containerRelativeFrame([.horizontal, .vertical],alignment: .topLeading)
    .containerBackground(for: .widget){
        Color("WidgetBackground")
    }
}

Update - adding configuration code
struct My_Widget_Large: Widget {
  let kind: String = "My_Widget_Large"


  var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
    IntentConfiguration(kind: kind, intent: SelectLocationIntent.self, provider: MyProvider()
    ) { entry in
        My_Widget_LargeEntryView(entry: entry)
    }
    .configurationDisplayName("Test Widget")
    .description("Terst widget")
    .supportedFamilies([.systemLarge])
    .contentMarginsDisabled()
  }
}


Try using contentMarginsDisabled()
Something like:
StaticConfiguration(kind: kind, provider: provider) { entry in
   Rectangle()
}
.contentMarginsDisabled()

And then add your own paddings

I had that in the Widget struct, I've added that code to the question to make it clear
